# Which version of the St Petersburg paradox is the original one?

Tags: mathematics, probability

There is are basically two versions of the St Petersburg paradox.

They differ only on a minor point, namely in the amount that is paid. In one version, $n$ heads and then tails gives a payout of $2^{n+1}$ (minus the price that was paid to play the game). In another version, $n$ heads and then tails gives a payout of $2^n$.

I'd like to know which version was originally used. I think the letters wherein the paradox was introduced are present in the second version of Ars conjectandi, 1713. However, I haven't been able to find the paradox or those letters in the versions of Ars conjectandi I found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See :

- [Pierre Remond de Montmort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Raymond_de_Montmort) (1713), [Essay d'analyse sur les jeux de hazard](https://books.google.fr/books?id=DIM_AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA402), *Extrait d'une Lettre de M.N.Bernoulli à M.de M... du 9 Septembre 1713* :

> *Cinquiéme Problème*. On demande la meme chose si A promet à B de lui donner des écus en cette progression $1, 2, 4, 8, 16$ etc. [*Fifth Problem*. One asks the same thing [see: *Fourth Problem*] if A promises to B to give him
>   some coins in this progression $1, 2, 4, 8, 16$ etc. ]